# How to copy array of objects from ajax call to observable array?

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have an function where i do ajax call and i get the data in callback. Something like this

```
function loadData(callback) {
   //do ajax
   if(callback) {
      callback(data.data);
   }
}
```

And if i call the function like

```
loadData(function(data) {
   return data;
})
```

it returns the data i need. How can i copy all the objects and its key/values to an `self.dataset = ko.observableArray([]);`
So i can use the data anywhere i want?

Comment: You could use the Mapping pluggin:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: `loadData(self.dataset)` writes to the observable array

Answer (score 0):

How I do it is by using the [Knockout Mapping Plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) and the `fromJSON` command (you might need to use `fromJS` depending on your data format) this maps the data as it comes from the source.

```
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://...',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, self.dataArray);
        }
    });
}
```